# Indice y elemento de una lista

Tags: python, lista, indices

Tengo esta lista:

```
l2 = [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 3), (4, 2), (2, 4)]
```

Y debo obtenet el indice y el elemento de la pareja cuya multiplicacion sea la mas alta. ¿Como accedo a los indice de cada pareja, como realizo la multiplicacion?

Intenté esto:

```
l2 = [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 3), (4, 2), (2, 4)]
i = 0
position = i
product =0
m = l2[i]

for i,j in l2:
    product += l2[i]*l2[j] 
    print(" es " + str(product))
```

Comment: ¿qué intentaste? entiendo que estás empezando en Python, es bueno intentar primero las cosas y luego preguntar las dudas croquetas

Comment: La forma de iterar es mediante un `for`. Esta sintaxis itera directamente sobre los elementos, pero si haces `enumerate(lista)` entonces cada iteración te dará un par (indice, elemento). En tu caso cada elemento es a su vez otro par. Puedes hacer por tanto `for indice, par in lista:` y la multiplicación será `par[0]*par[1]`. El resto te lo dejo a ti. Cuando intentes algo y topes con una duda, preguntas de nuevo.

Comment: Hola, Marie. Si estás haciendo esas preguntas tan básicas como cómo multiplicar o acceder a los elementos de una lista de tuplas, entonces lo que necesitas primero es leer algún tutorial básico sobre Python.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'
Yo lo que habia intentado era esto 
```l2 = [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 3), (4, 2), (2, 4)]
i = 0
position = i
product =0
m = l2[i]
for i,j in l2:
    product += l2[i]*l2[j]
print(" es " + str(product)) ```

Solo que da pena mostrar lo perdido que puede estar uno
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con `len(l2)` sabes la longitud de tu lista y puedes iterar e indexar en ella, luego solo es ir comparando para quedarte con la mayor multiplicación. Y en `ind` vas guardando el índice de la mayor multiplicación.

```
l2 = [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 3), (4, 2), (2, 4)]

ind = 0

for i in range(1, len(l2)):
    if(l2[i][0] * l2[i][1] > l2[ind][0] * l2[ind][1]):
        ind = i

print(str(ind) + " " + str(l2[ind][0] * l2[ind][1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Tambien podrías hacer lo siguiente para obtener lo que buscas:

```
l2 = [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 3), (4, 2), (2, 4)]

print(max(enumerate(l2), key=lambda par:par[1][0]*par[1][1]))
```

Perdon si algo esta mal en el formato, estoy en celular.

Edit: ya lo arreglé en una computadora.